# What is a resolve attachment?

Tags: vulkan

Vulkan spec says:

> Resolve Attachment
>
> A subpass attachment point, or image view, that is the target of a multisample resolve operation
> from the corresponding color attachment at the end of the subpass.

Can I get a more noob-friendly description of what a Resolve Attachment is?

Comment: How "noob friendly" does it need to be? Do you know what a "multisample resolve operation" is?

Comment: No, I don't know what a "multisample resolve operation" is.

Comment: Do you know what "multisampling" is? Not merely in its effects (ie: it does antialiasing), but how it actually works?

Comment: I only know that multisampling is used for antialiasing. Haven't used it much, yet, other than turning on some bits, here and there, related to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Resolving Multisample Images

During the resolve the samples corresponding to each pixel location in the source are converted to a single sample before being written to the destination. If the source formats are floating-point or normalized types, the sample values for each pixel are resolved in an implementation-dependent manner. If the source formats are integer types, a single sample’s value is selected for each pixel.

- [docs link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/html/vkspec.html#copies-resolve)

Using a Resolve Attachment you can "downsample" an image. I assume this can be more efficient than issuing a `vkCmdResolveImage` after the renderpass.